# Spring Kafka Batch Option: ClassCastException using SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

```
Trying to configure the Factory as below:
private ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> getKafkaContainerFactory()
        throws IOException {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(this.getConsumerFactory());//DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    ContainerProperties props = factory.getContainerProperties();
    props.setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.BATCH);
    props.setAckOnError(false);
    props.setBatchErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler());
    return factory;
}
```

with:

```
Kafka version : 1.0.2, spring-kafka:2.1.10.RELEASE & springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
```

getting the following exception:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler cannot be cast to org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create batch listener containers, add `factory.setBatchListener(true);`

Comment: It worked. (I had that option earlier but ran into another exception & reset my code to start from scratch, then missed to add it). Awesome and many thanks for the quick feedback. BTW, amazing work on Spring-Kafka!!!